# Django can not run 'install_labels' on neo4j Database

Tags: python, django, docker, neo4j, neomodel

I'm trying to set up a Docker container running React on the frontend, Django on the backend and Neo4j as the database. At the moment all three components are running correctly, but I just can't get Django to connect to the Neo4j database. I've probably read all the tutorials on the internet and tried all the things but it always comes up with some error and the database is unreachable or denies access.
I have also worked through this [tutorial](https://neo4j-examples.github.io/paradise-papers-django/tutorial/part03.html) and created the models accordingly. However, I always get an error when I run "python manage.py install_labels".

The error is:
neobolt.exceptions.SecurityError: Failed to establish secure connection to 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)'

Has anyone of you ever set up a similar environment or can help me?
Maybe Django is just not that suitable for it .... Basically I just want a React frontend and a Python backend working with a Neo4j database. And the whole thing please in a Docker image.
Are there any better alternatives for the backend?

Thanks in advance for your help!

In the following you can see all of my files that are important in my opinion.

My Dockerfiles look like this:

```
# Django Dockerfile
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /myapp

COPY /myapp/django_backend/requirements.txt /myapp/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY /myapp/django_backend /myapp/
```

```
# React Dockerfile
FROM node:17-alpine3.14

WORKDIR /myapp

COPY /myapp/react_frontend /myapp

RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  react:
    image: react_frontend:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./myapp/react_frontend/public:/myapp/public
      - ./myapp/react_frontend/src:/myapp/src
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

   django:
     image: django_backend:latest
     command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
     volumes:
       - ./myapp/django_backend:/myapp
     ports:
       - 8000:8000
     expose:
       - 8000
     depends_on:
       - neo4j
     links:
       - neo4j

  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:4.4.3
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 7474:7474
      - 7687:7687
    volumes:
      - neo4j_data:/neo4j/data
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=none
      - encrypted=False

volumes:
  neo4j_data:
```

My requirements.txt:

```
Django
djangorestframework
django-cors-headers

psycopg2

# neo4j and django connection
django-neomodel
neomodel
neo4j-driver
```

And the settings.py from the Django backend:

```
from neomodel import config
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(_file_).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-+b-r19ofy)&x20j57qzv1f_zn(*6gld6!&bg&g@8=m=hz)8@as'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # for api
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    # for connection with database
    'django_neomodel',

    'techstack'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_backend.wsgi.application'

config.DATABASE_URL = 'bolt://neo4j:neo4j@neo4j:7687'
config.ENCRYPTED_CONNECTION = False

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

I also tried to see if I could reach the database via the GraphDatabase.driver and that worked. The following test.py file is on the top level of my container and I can run it directly from the terminal and the database object is created successfully. Only the command 'python manage.py install_labels' still does not work and aborts with the error 'neobolt.exceptions.SecurityError: Failed to establish secure connection to 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)'.

```
# test.py:
from neo4j import GraphDatabase

class HelloWorldExample:

    def __init__(self, uri, user, password):
        self.driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=(user, password), encrypted=False)

    def close(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def print_greeting(self, message):
        with self.driver.session() as session:
            greeting = session.write_transaction(self._create_and_return_greeting, message)
            print(greeting)

    @staticmethod
    def _create_and_return_greeting(tx, message):
        result = tx.run("CREATE (a:Greeting) "
                        "SET a.message = $message "
                        "RETURN a.message + ', from node ' + id(a)", message=message)
        return result.single()[0]


# if name == "main":
greeter = HelloWorldExample("bolt://neo4j:7687", "", "")
greeter.print_greeting("hello, world")
greeter.close()
```

Comment: `'bolt://neo4j:neo4j@localhost:7687'` points to localhost, but your database is in another container. Try to use `'bolt://neo4j:neo4j@neo4j:7687'`

Comment: Also, the `django` container is on its own network `neo4j_network`, but the actual `neo4j` container is on the Compose-provided `default` network.  I'd recommend removing all of the `networks:` blocks in the file so that everything is on `default`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! The network was indeed a mistake and so only through countless attempts. Initially, I had not configured any networks or set the network for both containers. I updated my compose file and took out the network. 

With the address 'bolt://neo4j:neo4j@neo4j:7687' I get now however the following:  error message:
neobolt.exceptions.SecurityError: Failed to establish secure connection to 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)'

Comment: I also tried to add the line 'config.ENCRYPTED_CONNECTION = False' in settings.py and 'encrypted=False' in compose for the database, but this did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check your requirements.txt. It says neo4j-driver>=1.7,<2.0 which means you should be using neo4j version 3.5 or below. Look at this documentation:

> https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/neo4j-supported-versions/

Comment: Hey Jose, 
thanks for your help. I changed the requirements, so that it uses the newest versions.
I also found out that my Django can actually access the Database. Please have a look at the (new) last part of my question. 
I don't know exactly what the problem is, but somehow the 'python manage.py install_labels' command is not working. Maybe the line 'config.ENCRYPTED_CONNECTION = False' in the settings.py file can't be processed correctly?